# $\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{x^n}{x+e^x} $ without using LHR

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, probability-limit-theorems

Prove that for each n∈N. $\lim_{x\to \infty} \dfrac {x^n}{x+e^x}=0$ using basic $\varepsilon$ - $N$ method.
I tried as 
We have $\left|\dfrac{x^n}{x+e^x}\right|<\varepsilon$.
I take $x>1$ and it become
$\left|\dfrac{1}{x+e^x}\right|<\varepsilon$.
Using $e^x>x$
I got $\left|\dfrac{1}{2e^x}\right|<\varepsilon$.
From that I got $N=\ln\left(\dfrac{1}{2\varepsilon}\right)$.
But my problem is using this inequality I can choose a $\varepsilon$ such that $x$ can become $<1$.
I want to prove this for every positive $x$ without using L hospital rule,
Can you help me?

Comment: There is problem with the way you proceed. when $x > 1$ you can't go from $\left|\dfrac{x^n}{x+e^x}\right|<\varepsilon$ to $\left|\dfrac{1}{x+e^x}\right|<\varepsilon$. You need to use the fact that $e^{x} > x^{n}/n!$ for any value of $n$.

Comment: I used when $x>1$, $x^n>1$

Comment: And how the above inequality helps in proving this

Comment: Since $e^{x} > x^{n + 1}/(n + 1)!$ it means that $x^{n}/(x + e^{x}) < x^{n}/(x + x^{n + 1}/(n + 1)!) = (n + 1)!x^{n}/((n + 1)!x + x^{n + 1}) < (n + 1)!/x$. Hence this can be made less than $\varepsilon$ if $x > (n + 1)!/\varepsilon$. Thus we can take $N = (n + 1)!/\varepsilon$

Comment: Ok,my question is I have given a $€$ and I want to find a $N$  which is function of $€$ ,how will I find that $N$ using this inequality

Comment: check my edited comment. I have given value of $N$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11260/discussion-between-jibin-joy-k-and-paramanand-singh)

Comment: I don't know my understanding is correct or not.but I understood the basic definition of limit converge to inftyas "for every €>0 there exist a no N such that x>N implies $|f(x)-L|<€$.so we have the inequality $|\frac {x^n}{x+e^x}|<€$

Comment: Continuation of above comment.so although your inequality is correct.i.e.$|\frac{x^n}{x+e^x}|<\frac{(n+1)!}{x}$.      But that doesn't implies $|\frac{(n+1)!}{x}<€$,

Comment: It seems you need to revisit definition of limit. The inequality regarding epsilon is not a logical consequence, but is enforced by choosing a sufficient value of N and setting x > N.

Comment: Can you elaborate it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments exchanged between me and OP, it seems that a detailed step by step answer is needed. I am trying to provide one here. Before we begin it is better to clarify the definition of limit of a function $f(x)$ as $x \to \infty$.

*A function $f(x)$ is said to tend to a limit $L$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$ (written symbolically as $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = L$ if for any given real number $\varepsilon > 0$ it is possible to find a positive real number $N$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$ whenever $x > N$.*

So we have to choose an $N$ (corresponding to an $\varepsilon$) such that $x > N \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$. From the comments by OP, it seems that OP believes that the implication is in other direction i.e. $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow x > N$. But this is not the case. However there is another catch. In practice when we have to find an actual expression for $N$ in terms of $\varepsilon$ we try to proceed with the starting equation $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$ and try to see what limitation it implies on the values of $x$ and then hope to find that we get some limitation of the form $x > N$. Perhaps this procedure to find $N$ is probably the source of confusion for OP.

I will try to illustrate this point in reference to the current question. We have been provided with $f(x) = \dfrac{x^{n}}{x + e^{x}}$ and $L = 0$ and we have to verify that $L$ is in fact the limit of $f(x)$ as $ x \to \infty$ according to the definition given above. The verification has to be in form of finding an $N$ corresponding to an $\varepsilon$.

So we have to find an $N > 0$ such that $x > N$ implies $|f(x)| < \varepsilon$ i.e. $\left|\dfrac{x^{n}}{x + e^{x}}\right| < \varepsilon$. So we try to figure out **how we can make $|x^{n}/(x + e^{x})|$ smaller than $\varepsilon$**. Clearly we see that $|x^{n}/(x + e^{x})| = x^{n}/(x + e^{x}) < x^{n}/e^{x}$ and hence **it is sufficient if we can make $x^{n}/e^{x}$ smaller than $\varepsilon$**. Again we note that $$e^{x} = 1 + x + \frac{x^{2}}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{x^{n + 1}}{(n + 1)!} + \cdots$$ and hence $e^{x} > x^{n + 1}/(n + 1)!$ and therefore $x^{n}/e^{x} < (n + 1)!/x$. So **it is sufficient to make $(n + 1)!/x$ smaller than $\varepsilon$ i.e. $(n + 1)!/x < \varepsilon$**. Now this thing we can easily do if we make $x > (n + 1)!/\varepsilon$.

If we follow the logic written in bold lines above then we can see that taking $x > (n + 1)!/\varepsilon$ is sufficient for our initial goal of making $|x^{n}/(x + e^{x})| < \varepsilon$. It follows that if we put $N = (n + 1)!/\varepsilon$ then $x > N$ implies $|f(x)| < \varepsilon$. Thus $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = 0$.

The problem here is technically simple but probably because of the symbolism of epsilons it looks like a tough exercise. One has to understand that what we need here is a little common sense and a bit knowledge of inequalities. I hope I have tried to provide a very simple answer (and sorry for the length).

Comment: Thank you,I understand my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Fix an $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We must show that for $x$ sufficiently large, $\frac{x^n}{x+e^x}<\epsilon$. If we make the denominator smaller, the expression gets larger. Using the Taylor series $e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\ldots$, we have
$$
\bigg|\frac{x^n}{x+e^x}\bigg|
\leq\bigg|\frac{x^n}{x+1+x+\ldots+\frac{1}{n!}x^n+\frac{1}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}}\bigg|
\leq\bigg|\frac{x^n}{\frac{1}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}}\bigg|
=\frac{(n+1)!}{x}
$$
Since $n$ is fixed, by choosing $x$ sufficiently large, we can make this expression as small as we like.

Comment: I want to prove this in €-N method.that is I want to find a N function of € such that basic inequality will valid